# What else can be used instead of < or > in HTML codes?

Tags: html

When we do any HTML coding we use `<` and `>` to specify a tag which any browser does not show as text but as display. Can anything else(any coding, for HTML) be used instead of these symbols?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question.  Are you asking what other `&` codes exist in HTML?  Or are you asking what other ways exist to display `<` and `>` symbols?

Comment: Actually I am asking, as we use these symbols for starting and closing a tag, in the start of a tag and in the last of the tag. Can we use anything else for starting a tag and closing as well?

Answer (score 2):

In practical terms: No. Only `<` and `>` mark the start and end of a tag in HTML.

In theoretical terms only (because this is **not supported by any mainstream browser**), in HTML 4 and earlier you could use SHORT TAGS. The syntax for this is to use `/` instead of `>` to end the start tag and then `/` instead of the entire end tag:

For example:

```
<title/This is the title/
```

or

```
<br/ <!-- note that the end tag for br elements must be omitted in HTML 4 and earlier -->
```

Some other SGML features may allow other options, but they would also not be supported by browsers.

---

**The following is my answer to what appeared to be the original question after someone had edited it to show `&lt;` instead of `<`**.

In theory, for HTML 4 and earlier, you can use [CDATA sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.5) … but they never saw widespread support in browsers so aren't of any practical value in HTML.

There is also the `<xmp>` element, which is obsolete. The HTML 5 draft marks it as [non-conforming](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) and says:

> Use pre and code instead, and escape "`<`" and "`&`" characters as "`&lt;`" and "`&amp;`" respectively

The W3C Wiki has [this to say about xmp](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/xmp):

> No, really. don't use it.

Character references (`&lt;` and co) are the correct tools for the job. Any desire to avoid them is better replaced by learning to love a programatic solution or the find & replace feature of your editor.

Comment: Don't forget numeric HTML entities, in both decimal and hexadecimal.

Comment: I class those as the same thing :)

Comment: Perhaps, but I suspect the OP with extremely basic knowledge of HTML does not. If the question is _"I'm trying to work around some lame filter that is blocking `&lt;`; is there any other way to display a `<`?"_ then numeric entities might just be the answer. :p

Comment: Well, it's all stackoverflows' mistake, you didn't get what I tried to say. If you get to see & l t ; (not the spaces within), it's not that, they are symbols. If you say about numeric entities, would they work as tag start and tag end?

Comment: @Md.ShadabAkhtar — The mistake was not stackoverflow's, it was a combination of you using an HTML entity instead of using the Stackoverflow markup for "this is code" and someone editing the question to add the "this is code" markup around your entity. I have edited your question to make it clear what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking whether it is possible to use characters other than `<` and `>` as tag start and tag end characters. For example, can one somehow define that `[` and `]` are used instead, so that we would write `[p]` and not `<p>`.

The answer is no. HTML was formally based on SGML, which has provisions for such definitions; in SGML, `<` and `>` are just “reference concrete syntax” characters for abstract “start of tag” and “end of tag” notations. But HTML was never actually implemented as SGML-based, and the HTML specifications even formally fixed the syntax to use `<` and `>`. And XML, the simplified version of SGML, upon which XHTML is based, has no provisions for setting such syntax features.

Comment: So, you're saying it's not possible any how. Can you tell about any such language which do not use such symbols for starting or closing tag? Does any such language even exist?

Comment: In SGML, you can select your tag start and tag end characters within broad limits. However, SGML-based systems generally use the reference concrete syntax for them, i.e. `<` and `>`. And many SGML-based systems have nowadays moved to XML, which does not allow such variation. So you would probably need to dig into the history of SGML to find a particular system that uses another convention.